# How to collect with grouping by with reducing downstream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a problem with `groupingBy` collecting. In my case all elements in list have unique `addressType` value. I want to get a `Map<String, Address>` but have `Map<String, Optional<Address>>`

```
List<Address> list = ....
Map<String, Optional<Address>> collect = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Address::getAddressType,
             Collectors.reducing((o, o2) -> o)));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `all elements in list have unique addressType value`, there's no reason to use `Collectors.groupingBy` in this case. Use `Collectors.toMap` instead:

```
Map<String, Address> collect = 
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Address::getAddressType,
                                  Function.identity()));
```